# Multiple errors with selenium, python and chrome

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I cant find the soluiton for this errors, the code is really simple but i can't fix it, please help

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("www.google.com")
driver.close()
```

i tried with geckodriver, and with the path in all the ways, but there's no change

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/lautaro/.local/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 72, in start
self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chromedriver'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/lautaro/.local/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "/home/lautaro/.local/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' 
executable needs to be in PATH. Please see 
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Comment: Which errors do you see?

Comment: i forgot adding them lol